# Access column values from a particular sheet, from multiple excels

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to access multiple excel files present in a folder,then find a particular sheet and then search a particular column(header is in the first row of the sheet). The column contains numeric values and I need to sum all the values for that column of the sheet and then paste the sum in a table creating a new excel.The output excel should contain the table having the sum of the values for that column of all the excels I accesse

**PlannedEffort**  || **Actual effort** ||  **Deployed By**||     **Month**

The bold lettered fields are headers of an excel sheet and I need to find the sum of the numeric values of the column "Actual Effort",for all the excels present in the folder.

Following is my code.I am stuck at reading the column values after searching for the column.I am using C# language with Microsoft.Interop dll ver 12.0 and MS excel 2007 is present in the system

class Program
    {

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();

        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Sheets sheets;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range range;
        System.Array myValues;
        string findName = "Actual Effort";

        string[] path = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Documnents\Projects\ReadExcelApp\*.xls");

       foreach (string xlPath in path)
        {
            xlWorkBook = application.Workbooks.Open(xlPath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            sheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets;
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(3);
            range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

            string findColumnValue = RetrieveColumnValue(xlWorkSheet, findName);
           //string colCount = findColumnValue.(Stuck at this line:how to access the column values)

        }
    }
    public static string RetrieveColumnValue(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet, string findName)
    {
        Excel.Range rng = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
        Excel.Range rngResult = null;
        rngResult = rng.Find(findName, Type.Missing, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        if (rngResult != null)
        {
            Excel.Range cRng = null;
            int rowused = rng.Rows.Count;

            string returnStr;
            for (int i = 1; i < rowused; i++)
            {
                cRng = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, rngResult.Column];
                if (cRng != null)
                {
                    returnStr = cRng.Name.ToString();
                }

            }
            return returnStr;
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

}
```

Also,is it possible that once it is running,would I be able to execute the exe in a system having MS Office 2010?

Comment: Please provide sample input and fix the formatting and grammar of your question to make it easier for readers to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to sum the column values:

```
        decimal returnVal = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < rowused; i++) //NB: off-by-one error here? Shouldn't it be from 1 to <= rows ?
        {
            cRng = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, rngResult.Column];
            if (cRng != null)
            {
                decimal currentVal;
                if( decimal.TryParse(cRng.Value2.ToString(), out currentVal) )
                    returnVal += currentVal;
            }
        }
        return returnVal.ToString();
```